# Please set the default syntax highlighting for the discord.js tag to be JavaScript

Tags: support, feature-request, syntax-highlighting

[discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.js) questions are always about the JavaScript library for interacting with Discord's API.

Since questions using that tag would always be using JavaScript, I propose that the default syntax highlighting for the tag be set the same as [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Comment: Aren't you suppose to use the body of the post to argue for why you'd want this? What is the current syntax highlighting for discord.js? Why is it bad? How will setting it to JavaScript make it better?

Comment: @Scratte There isn't any. That's why it's bad. Because JS is the language it should use. There's not really much to argue

Comment: @Nick So that could go into the post, no?

Comment: It could, but there's not really any reason to, the title contains literally everything actually necessary to know the request and understand it, including the reasoning

Comment: Tried to make the body a proposal.

Comment: Why though? Questions about libraries are largely meant to have language tags included, which would make this a non-issue

Comment: I do think that tags with an incredibly high volume of questions should be handled with a little more care as it is pretty much infeasible to put such tags on your watch list, the noise level is really high. discord.js is implied to be javascript, so why would it be a good idea to have to add the javascript tag to it just to get highlighting working.

Comment: The problem is that those who post discord.js questions *very frequently* don't tag the question with JavaScript. [8000 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdiscord.js%5D+-javascript+is%3Aq). What harm would setting the syntax language do? Yes, one could edit all those questions to add JS, but many of those questions don't really have to do with how JS  works, but how a particular feature of discord.js works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that is not needed.

There already is a tag with the correct highlighter configured. That tag is called [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

In the excerpt and wiki of [discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.js) it says:

> Consider also using the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.

which makes sense. If the Discord askers where only a bit more careful when they tag their question, all would be fine.

Comment: Yes... I literally just added that... :)

Comment: There are *some* questions where you only want the library but not the main language. With that said, it's *very few* cases. The fact is that the majority of questions (at least around [[tag:javascript]]) are in some ways connected to the main language to an extent. It's quite often they *are* about the main language but just happen to show up when the user used the library.

Comment: @IanKemp I didn't expect an accept vote without having a merciless fight over it ... are you OK?

Comment: @rene I simply forgot that the rule is for there always to be a specific language tag. Such happens when you're trying to multi-task between interminable meetings and Stack Overflow...

Comment: Yeah, the meetings are killing us ...

Comment: @VLAZ I don't know anything about discord.js, but I think there are plenty of cases in which tagging with only the library/framework and not with the broader language makes sense, when the question is about something specific to the framework. I think [many of the questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdiscord.js%5D+-javascript+is%3Aq) are good examples of that. If the question is specific to discord.js, being a JS expert will often not provide any benefit.

Comment: *Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.*